# Find two groups in array that have an exact portion

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, derivative

I need help to find 2 groups in array that have an exact portion.
e.g. arr = {8, 1, 4, 9, 3} and difference = 1, the groups will be {8, 1, 3} (12) and {4, 9} (13) and finally, print the groups without  print another options that the code tried before, like:

```
8, 1, 3
9, 4
```

I don't know how to solve it, because each number in a group can be placed in different place, I tried to do it recursively but it didn't work.

A java code will be helpful!

Comment: no, each cell contains a test result of feature, and I want to see if there is a big difference and the features of the system doesn't work as they suppose to.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be simplified if you thought about permutations of the numbers. You can simply get a list of permutations from your numbers, sum up each permutation and sort. If you find the correct difference between the numbers, then you can print them out. I suggest you look up more on doing permutations in java (which will involve some recursion).